# How to create a bot for gtalk that search for online help Java?

Tags: java, web-applications, xmpp, bots, instant-messaging

I have idea that for people who use gtalk especially for developers, how to write a bot that recieve question from one developer and ask other online developers for help based on their programming skills?

1. Bot added by the user to gtalk and
   user will gave his/her skills at
   first time
2. Then if someone ask a
   question application will search for
   the online users who have similar
   skills to question

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could just link to stackoverflow, and be done with it :)